# Calculate group mean for an arange column in Polars dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

I have the following code in polars:

```
import datetime
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
        "date": [
            datetime.date(2022, 1, 1),
            datetime.date(2022, 1, 1),
            datetime.date(2022, 1, 11),
            datetime.date(2022, 1, 11),
            datetime.date(2022, 2, 1),
            datetime.date(2022, 2, 1),
            datetime.date(2022, 2, 1),
        ],
        "value": [1, 2, 3, None, 5, 6, None],
    }
)

df.groupby_dynamic("date", by="id", every="1mo", period="1mo", closed="both").agg(
    pl.arange(1, pl.count() + 1) - pl.arange(1, pl.count() + 1).filter(pl.col("value").is_not_null()).mean(),
)
```

But, when I run it, I got the following error which I don't quite understand.

```
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: index out of bounds: the len is 1 but the index is 1
```

The behavior I want to achieve is: for each group, create a natural sequence from 1 to the number of rows in that group, and subtract from it the average over non-null in the "value" column in that group. (return null if all "value" in that group are null).

To be more specific, the result I want is

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ date       ┆ arange           │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---              │
│ i64 ┆ date       ┆ list[f64]        │
╞═════╪════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0] │
│ 1   ┆ 2022-02-01 ┆ [0.0]            │
│ 2   ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ [-1.0, 2.0, 1.0] │
│ 2   ┆ 2022-02-01 ┆ [0.0]            │
│ 3   ┆ 2022-02-01 ┆ [null]           │
└─────┴────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: for `2022-01` and id `1`, with `closed='both'`, the values are `1`, `3`, `5`, whose average is `3`. So wouldn't the first row of your expected result be `[-2, -1, 0]`?

Comment: The values in the ‘value’ are not needed for calculation whatsoever, just need it for null checking. The average I want to take is over the natural sequence 1 to number of rows.

Comment: The error looks like a "bug" - if you use `.filter(~pl.col("value").is_null())` instead - it runs - but it doesn't do what you want, you'd want the filter on the left hand side - but then you have a "hole" where each null is. Even then, some of the results look odd. I'm not entirely sure if using filter on one side of a list comparison is supposed to work.

Comment: Yeah, that's what confuses me. Doing filter mean on regular column works, but gives me error on pl.arange, which makes me think pl.arange is not kind of regular column already in dataframe.

Comment: It looks like there was an issue with `.filter()` in a groupby context which has just been fixed. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/7041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like perhaps you need to "explode" and then implement your logic.

**Edit:** with `"value": [1, None, 3, 4, 5, 6, None]`

```
(
   df
   .groupby_dynamic(index_column="date", by="id", every="1mo", period="1mo", closed="both").agg(
      pl.exclude("date"))
   .with_row_count("group")
   .explode("value")
   .with_columns(
      (pl.arange(1, pl.count() + 1) 
       - pl.arange(1, pl.count() + 1)
           .filter(pl.col("value").is_not_null())
           .mean())
      .over("group"))
)
```

```
shape: (9, 5)
┌───────┬─────┬────────────┬───────┬────────┐
│ group | id  | date       | value | arange │
│ ---   | --- | ---        | ---   | ---    │
│ u32   | i64 | date       | i64   | f64    │
╞═══════╪═════╪════════════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 0     | 1   | 2022-01-01 | 1     | -1.0   │
│ 0     | 1   | 2022-01-01 | 3     | 0.0    │
│ 0     | 1   | 2022-01-01 | 5     | 1.0    │
│ 1     | 1   | 2022-02-01 | 5     | 0.0    │
│ 2     | 2   | 2022-01-01 | null  | -1.5   │
│ 2     | 2   | 2022-01-01 | 4     | -0.5   │
│ 2     | 2   | 2022-01-01 | 6     | 0.5    │
│ 3     | 2   | 2022-02-01 | 6     | 0.0    │
│ 4     | 3   | 2022-02-01 | null  | null   │
└───────┴─────┴────────────┴───────┴────────┘
```

You could use the `group` column to piece them back together afterwards.

Comment: I think the mean column is not correct - it is correct just for my example by accident. I want to have the mean after filtered out the null from value. For example, if "value" is [1, None, 3, 4, 5, 6, None]. Then the mean I expect for id 2 on 2022-01-01 should be 2.5.

Comment: Understood. The `.filter()` part was missing.